# could not open extension control file for Citext in postgresql 10

Tags: elixir, ecto, postgresql-10

I just installed postgresql 10 in Fedora 28. then I did a mix ecto.migrate but it says

> ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 58P01 (undefined_file): could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-10/share/extension/citext.control":
>   No such file or directory

I installed postgresql10-contrib also..

pg_config --sharedir
returns

```
/usr/share/pgsql
```

and I can find

```
/usr/share/pgsql/extension/citext.control
```

file.
but not in /usr/pgsql-10/share/extension directory.

what am I missing?

Comment: When you look at: `http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/6/idpl/44117010/dir/fedora_other/com/postgresql10-contrib-10.4-1PGDG.f28.x86_64.rpm` and search for `citext.control`, you will find that `/usr/pgsql-10/share/extension/citext.control` is part of the package. So if you install the contrib package, it should reflect on your system accordingly

Comment: Yes I just installed "postgresql10-contrib-10.4-1PGDG.f28.x86_64.rpm" and it works! Thank you! @KevinJohnson

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS or RHEL, install the Postgres Extensions library `postgresql-contrib`. You can do this with `dnf` with the following command:

```
sudo dnf install postgresql-contrib
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: on amazon linux 2023, i had to use `postgresql15-contrib`

Answer (score 1):

Just installed "postgresql10-contrib-10.4-1PGDG.f28.x86_64.rpm" and it works!

Comment: On Alpine `apk add postgresql-contrib` do the job