# Could not open extension control file citext.control

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, ubuntu, psycopg2

### Environment(s)

Ubuntu 20.04 & Debian 10 with Python 3.8 or 3.7, respectively.

Postgresql versions 11, 12, and 14 have been tried.

Psycopg2-binary 2.8.6

### Overview

I'm attempting to install a Django project, and I'm getting this error:

`psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/citext.control": No such file or directory`

The psycopg devs informed me this is likely an issue with the postgresql-contrib libraries. Similarly, others have been able to [fix this error by installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536396/could-not-open-extension-control-file-for-citext-in-postgresql-10) `postgresql-contrib`, however, this does not work for me. I've also tried installing `postgresql-12`.

I can see that citext.control is available in `/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/citext.control`, so I tried `ln -s /usr/share/postgresql/12 /usr/share/pgsql` with no effect.

I also ran `CREATE EXTENSION citext;` in Postgres, also without effect.

Any support with this would be greatly appreciated, as I was hoping to have this project live already!

Thanks so much.

### Trace

```
Running migrations:
  Applying core.0043_install_ci_extension_pg...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/citext.control": No such file or directory


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/janeway/src/utils/management/commands/install_janeway.py", line 58, in handle
    call_command('migrate')
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 131, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 202, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/operations.py", line 17, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS %s" % schema_editor.quote_name(self.name))
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 136, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/user/venvs/janeway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/citext.control": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed `postgresql-contrib` on the local django server rather than the remote DB server. Installing on the same server as Postgresql resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing `python3-psycopg2` from the packaging system instead?

My Ubuntu 20 setup has this installed, and postgresql connections work with django.

`ii  python3-psycopg2    2.8.4-2    amd64     Python 3 module for PostgreSQL`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Anurag
I just tried using `python3-psycopg2` from apt, without any success (I passed it into the venv using --system-site-packages).

I separately tried changing from psycopg2-binary to psycopg2 in pip, also without any success.